# Running bat file with scheduled task and failing with 'There are no child processes to wait for'

Tags: git, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm running a `bat` file from `Task Scheduler` and am getting a last run result of `There are no child processes to wait for. (0x80070080).` without the intended result of the script. If I run the script manually it works like a charm. It is just doing an automated `git` `commit` and `push`. Any searching I do on the error proves to be a bit useless.
Anyone have any insight for me?

The `bat` file contains the following:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
Set hname=%COMPUTERNAME%
cd %HOME%\my_dir
git config --global user.name "Batch Script"
git config --global user.email "bat@test.com"
git add --all
git commit -m "File Backup: %mydate%_%mytime%_%hname%"
git push  2>&1
EXIT
```

**Things I have tried:**

- running as .bat or .cmd (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd))
- changing program/script to be 'cmd.exe' and arguments to be /c "C:\mypath\myscript.bat" (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304652/run-a-batch-file-from-task-scheduler-is-not-working-with-a-java-command))
- changing program/script to be 'test.bat' and 'Start in' to be "C:\mypath" (recommended [here](https://richardstk.com/2012/06/15/scheduled-task-to-run-a-batch-file/#comment-6873))
- running as `SYSTEM`

All of these result in the same error message as listed above.

- Adding `| Out-Null` after `2>&1` results in the error message now being `The extended attributes are inconsistent`

Comment: Read this about the difference between bat and cmd  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Comment: Task Scheduler bat vs cmd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304652/run-a-batch-file-from-task-scheduler-is-not-working-with-a-java-command

Comment: @RandySchuman, how is the BAT-vs.-CMD topic related to this question? would you mind to explain, please?

Comment: It matters if you have a .bat extension.I assume that you do since you reference bat. One of the articles states that running a .bat file manually is not the same as running it from Task Scheduler. There are differences. One of those being how errorlevels are handled. So in other words, try renaming it to .cmd to see what happens.

Comment: If you are running the task as "System", another thing you could check is if there are some environment variables that were set for your user profile, but not system (global).

Comment: I had actually already tested with `.bat` and `.cmd` but alas both have the same result. I've also double checked and I am running it as myself with highest privileges.

Comment: I am still trying to find an answer for you. I can find similar programs with the same message where people had success with by using "call" or "start /wait" in the batch file. One git user had a forking problem and wrote the batch file in Bash and that fixed it. They just released a new version 2 days ago. Worth a shot. "Git's .exe files are now code-signed, helping with performance when being run with Windows File Protection."

Comment: @RandySchuman Awesome, I will definitely look into this when I get in on Monday :) Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: No luck with `START /WAIT`. Looking into running bash scripts but looks like I'll need some extra software (I'm using `Server 2012`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker figured it out!

The `HOME` variable actually isn't defined when you are logged out. So once I explicitly defined the `HOME` variable in my script, things worked perfectly.

**The Fix:**

I added `$env:HOME = "C:\myHomePath"` before the `git` commands.